# parent class to return subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Its hard to explain in word what I'm after but hopefully the code example below with the comments is sufficient. Basically I want the `SubClass sc = new Subclass().method1()` line to return the Subclass instance.

```
public class SuperClass {

    public SuperClass method1()
    {
       //do whatever
       return this
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    //we inherit method 1

    //method2
    public SubClass method2()
    {
       //do whatever
       return this
    }
}

//succesfully returns instance of Sublass, but...
SubClass sc = new Subclass().method2() 

//...the following line returns an instance of SuperClass and not Sublass
//I want Sublass's instance, without having to using overides
//Is this possible?

SubClass sc = new Subclass().method1()
```

**EDIT: ----------------------------usecase scenario-------------------------------**

```
Message myMessage =  new ReverseTransactionMessageBuilder()
                    .policyNo(POLICY_NO) //on ReverseTransactionMessageBuilder
                    .audUserId(AUD_USER_ID) //on inherited MessageBuilder
                    .audDate(new Date()) //on inherited MessageBuilder
                    .processNo(EProcessConstants.FINANCE_MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT.getProcessCd()) //on inherited MessageBuilder
                    .serviceName("finance.ProcessReversalCmd") //on inherited MessageBuilder
                    .create(); //create is overridden so this is ReverseTransactionMessageBuilder
```

First thing youl notice is that sbrattla way allows me to call these .audDate () .xxx() methods in any order. With the class construct above you are forced to call the method on the sublcass last (or use a really ugly cast)

Comment: I agree. It should work.

Comment: No, not for the usecase that I intend to use it for

Comment: If you cast it to SubClass from SuperClass.method1(), doesn't that take away the entire point of having a superclass? If you, at a later point, decide to use SuperClass with another class (NewSubClass), then you'd still be stuck with SuperClass casting all instances to SubClass - and not to NewSubClass. I'd go for generics, where you have the chance to tell the superclass which type it should cast the returned object to.

Comment: Can you show your usecase please? Is it related to [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java)?

Comment: Sure, Ill edit the question quick, but I allready have my answer

Comment: Oh just saw the second part of your sentence now. Yes, it does look suprisngly similar to Fluent Interface, except my create is called last which allows me to validate the object that was constructed as a valid message. Youl notice in the usecase above that the last call does not return the builder but rather the "product" a Message instance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to do something like:

```
public class SuperClass<T> {

  public T method1() {
    return (T) this;
  }

}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass<SubClass> {

  public SubClass method2() {
    return (SubClass) this;
  }

}
```

You can read more about Java Generics in the "[Generics Introduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)", but briefly explained you're telling SuperClass to cast the returned instance to T which represents a type you define. In this case, it's SubClass.

Comment: No worries. You're more than welcome to "accept" my answer if it was what you were looking for :-)

Comment: You answered so quickly, I just had to wait a while before I could click accept.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use generic method like the following:

```
class Parent {
  public <T extends Parent> T instance() {
    return (T) this;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
}

class Test {
  public static void main() {
    Child child = new Parent().instance();
  }
}
```